# Compiler error Select Single Count when in Loop SQL

Tags: loops, select, count, abap

I have made a table where the material number, material text and so on have been added (selected_materials). Now I wanted to create a loop with this table so that it counts in the `EKPO` table how often the material number was mentioned in order to use it afterwards.

For the below code, the compiler says that `WHERE <selected_material>-matnr` is invalid, even though `WRITE: ... <selected_material>-matnr = ...` is valid.

```
  LOOP AT selected_materials ASSIGNING <selected_material>.

    DATA: lv_count TYPE i.

    SELECT SINGLE COUNT(*)
      From Ekpo 
      INTO lv_count 
      WHERE <selected_material>-matnr = Ekpo-matnr.

    WRITE: <selected_material>-maktx, <selected_material>-matnr, <selected_material>-meins, <selected_material>-msehl, <selected_material>-ekpo_count.
    NEW-LINE.

  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: If there is already the question and it was answered there, it would be good if someone could lead me there. At least I did not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` condition is not correct, it has to be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * )
  FROM ekpo 
  INTO lv_count 
  WHERE matnr EQ <selected_material>-matnr.
```

Please note `SINGLE` is also removed, as (I guess) the question is, how many entries are in `EKPO` for the material number (`SELECT COUNT( * )`...) and not, if there is at least one at all (`SELECT SINGLE COUNT( * )`...)

One more thing: In the `WRITE`, you display the field: -ekpo_count, however in the `SELECT COUNT( * )` lv_count is used.

Answer (score 2):

Before ABAP 7.40 SP 05, the operand on the left of the operator had to be a column name (cf József Szikszai answer).

From ABAP 7.40 SP 05, there is the "[strict mode](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopensql_strict_mode_740_sp05.htm)" which allows more complex SQL features. The strict mode is mainly activated by using the `@` character before the names of ABAP variables, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( * )
  FROM ekpo 
  WHERE @lv_matnr = ekpo~matnr
  INTO @lv_count .
```

NB: if a column name is used on the right side the "table alias" is required (`ekpo~matnr`) and in strict mode the INTO clause is to be positioned at the end (tested with ABAP 7.52)